# Executing a cron 9 to 5 and at midnight

Tags: cron

It's simple for the ones who understand it but for me most of the times it's a big puzzle.

I want to execute a PHP script 5 minutes after each hour from 9 to 5 and i want to run it once more 5 minutes after midnight.

- 00:05
- 09:05
- 10:05
- 11:05
- 12:05
- 13:05
- 14:05
- 15:05
- 16:05
- 17:05

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

crontab will look like

```
 5 0,9-17 * * * my job
```

fields are

- minutes
- hour
- day of the month
- month
- day of the week 0 and 7 being sunday.

see man 5  crontab

Answer (score 1):

> **5 0,9-17 * * * path of script**

Above crontab explained below.

This will execute the script as you expect.

- 5      - 5th minute
- 0      - 00 hour
- 9-17   - 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 Hours
- `*` - Every Day
- `*` -Every Month
- `*` -  Every Week